# How to copy one textfield to another textfield dynamically in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I copy one textfield to another textfield dynamically in vb.net?

For example when I write something in text field 1 then it would also show at the same time in text field 2.

Comment: use `keydown` event of the textbox1.

Comment: please tell me in detail?

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far @AhadMurtaza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TextChanged event on first text box and in the event handler set text of second textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub b1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
        tf3.SelectedText = tf3.Text
        tf3.Copy()

        tf3.Text = ""
    End Sub
    Private Sub b2_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b2.Click

        tf2.Paste()

    End Sub